# Dropdown menu list too big

Tags: html, list, drop-down-menu, menu, html-lists

I want to have a dropdown list with some teams' names. They all go straight down, but I want them to go next to each other every 10 teams. I have tried messing with the margin, but it's not very useful.

Any help will be appreciated. If anyone can, I would like to make it very similar to the official NBA website https://www.nba.com/

The following code:

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav ul .menu-1 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

nav ul .menu-2 {
  margin-left: 88px;
}

nav ul .menu-3 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pliroforiki</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Standings</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Eastern Conference</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Western Conference</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Teams</a>
          <ul class="menu-1">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Atlanta Hawks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Boston Celtics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Brooklyn Nets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Charlotte Hornets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Chicago Bulls</a>
            </li>
            <br />
            <br />
            <li>
              <a href="#">Cleveland Cavaliers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Dallas Mavericks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Denver Nuggets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Detroit Pistons</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Golden State Warriors</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="menu-2">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Houston Rockets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Indiana Pacers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">LA Clippers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Los Angeles Lakers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Memphis Grizzlies</a>
            </li>
            <br />
            <br />
            <li>
              <a href="#">Miami Heat</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Milwaukee Bucks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Minnesota Timberwolves</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">New Orleans Pelicans</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">New York Knicks</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="menu-3">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Oklahoma City Thunder</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Orlando Magic</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Philadelphia 76ers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Phoenix Suns</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Portland Trail Blazers</a>
            </li>
            <br />
            <br />
            <li>
              <a href="#">Sacramento Kings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">San Antonio Spurs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Toronto Raptors</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Utah Jazz</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Washington Wizards</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Playoffs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Players</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```